# Custom Soundcloud Javascript Player - Error Console

Tags: soundcloud

My custom JS player was working fine @ this url http://goo.gl/gJcuX  yesterday. But when I woke up, its just not working.

I'm getting this error console message as follows:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/66419962.json?client_id=REMOVED CLIENT ID&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
desirednoise.com:137TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'track.user.username')
```

So im not sure if i defined the object correctly or not? Should I remove something?
If you visit my website and click on post. Its not updating the player to the right style sheet. It goes off of link classes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SoundCloud API may be experiencing some downtime: http://status.soundcloud.com/